# Can someone confirm below array is a valid javascript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

We mainly write object or string in an array like this -

```
const arr = [{id: 123}, 'test']
```

And then we can access it through the index of the item -

```
console.log(arr[0], arr[1]);
```

But is it a valid array if we do like this -

```
const arr = [];
arr['id'] = {message: 'Hello'};
arr['name'] = 'test';
```

Because it doesn't giving any error and still i can access the items through -

```
console.log(arr['id'], arr['name'])
```

Comment: Why *wouldnt* that be valid? Given that it works it should already be obvious that it is valid. If it does not work it would be invalid.

Comment: Because typing something like `const arr = [id: '123']` basically gives error in any ide.

Comment: Technically, yes, this is still a valid object.  However, you are just taking advantage of the fact that in JS everything is an object-- your data is not being stored ordered in the array nor are you taking advantage of any of what an array data structure provides.  At this point, you might as well just use a plain object `{}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays in JS are sequence of elements that you can access with its indexes.

```
const arr = [{id: 123}, 'test']
```

So here `arr` contain two elements `{id: 123}` at index `0` and `'test'` at index `1`.

So, you can access array elements using `indexes` as:

```
console.log(arr[0], arr[1]);
```

```js
const arr = [{ id: 123 }, 'test'];
console.log(arr[0], arr[1]);
```

---

Also, Array is an object also so you can perform all sort of opertion on `arrays` that you can do with an `object` also

like assigning `value` to an object that you are doing here as:

```
arr['id'] = {message: 'Hello'};
arr['name'] = 'test';
```

accessing value from an array(object) as:

```
console.log(arr['id'], arr['name'])
```

> No one is stopping you to use arrays as an object. But it is not recommended.